# My laptop on ubuntu 22.04 began to overheat et turn very slowly at the start

Tags: overheating, temperature

I'm having a heating problem with my laptop.
specs :
hp elitebook 735 G6
ubuntu 22.04 ; cpu amd ryzen 3300U ; gpu radeon vega 6 ; 8go ram

Sometimes he starts as usual..
But sometimes it is very slow at the start and don't come back to normal even after 1 hour, and it's overheating even if I go in the file manager, even opening up the terminal..
I never had this problem before.
Usually, the cpu is around 35-45 degree at the start. Now it variate very fast and between 55 and 70 degree.

Any help, no information about overheating problem on ubuntu 22.04 found so I came here.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy fix but You could monitor it by checking if you have a process that take up too many CPU ressources with the `top` command in a terminal, also you have the `radeontop` command to show you the exact GPU usage and temperature